# MariaDB 10.3+ LEFT JOIN and user defined variable returns extra rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using MariaDB 10.0 the following SQL code returns just one row:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable1;
CREATE TABLE `TestTable1` (
  `SomeColumn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SomeColumn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO TestTable1 (`SomeColumn`) VALUES ('42');

SELECT * FROM TestTable1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT @p:=123 AS moo)  pd ON TRUE;

# SomeColumn, moo
42, 123
```

However, the same code in MariaDB 10.3 and 10.4 (unfortunately I don't have access to MariaDB 10.1 or 10.2) returns **two** rows!

```
# SomeColumn, moo
42, 123
42, 123
```

Note that **this only happens when using a user defined variable**. For instance, the following code only produces a single row, as expected:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable1;
CREATE TABLE `TestTable1` (
  `SomeColumn` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SomeColumn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO TestTable1 (`SomeColumn`) VALUES ('42');

SELECT * FROM TestTable1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 123 AS moo)  pd ON TRUE;
```

We have a lot of code that depends on this behavior and my goal is to make MariaDB 10.3+ behave 'the old way' and return only one row in this case.

NB: You can easily try this out yourself with https://dbfiddle.uk/

NB2: Bug report: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22264

Comment: Hmm left join should always have been a cross join

Comment: Why do you use JOIN if you are not doing JOIN-ing? You should use JOIN if you want to operate on sets to get union, intersection, left/rigt inner/outher join. Note that ON for you is TRUE, so any record on left and any record on right side will be added to your result (1 record left + 1 record right = 2 records). What you shown here is adding additional column with fixed value and for that you can just use one/first SELECT.
`SELECT TestTable1.*, @p AS moo;`

Comment: This is even more interesting because the code works as expected with CROSS JOIN, INNER JOIN and a LEFT JOIN if you remove the variable: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c4f7e01ad8b18779b86e675122a5d702

Comment: @VladimirVukanac : I realize this is the wrong way of doing things, however:
1) This is really a stripped down version of what the actual query is doing
2) We are in the process of upgrading from Mariadb 10.0 to 10.4 and we have a LOT of legacy SQL code that we can't afford to break. So good, or bad, it needs to keep producing the same output as before

Comment: @forpas Yes, I probably should have made it more clear in the post, the issue only happens when using a variable

Comment: 2 rows (for me) on 10.3.21, but one row on 10.0.28, 10.1.43, 10.2.30 and many flavors of MySQL.